# How to Get Object Centroid just from Object Boundary?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have 2 segmented images. One is otsu binary, and the other is outer boundary obtains from otsu's.

Otsu binary:

[image: Otsu binary]

Object boundary:

[image: Object boundary]

And code to find centroids like this:

```
def getCentroid(img):
   row, col = img.shape

   xVal = 0
   yVal = 0
   n = 0.0

   for x in range(0,row):
      for y in range(0,col):
         if (img[x,y] == 0):
            xVal += x
            yVal += y
            n += 1.0

   xVal /= n
   yVal /= n

   return [np.int64(np.round(xVal)),np.int64(np.round(yVal))]
```

But, it seems the code only works with otsu's. Here are the results:

Otsu binary:

[image: Otsu binary]

Object boundary:

[image: Object boundary]

So, how to find object centroid from object boundary?

Note: I don't want to use built-in function, cause i want to learn how the algorithm works.

Comment: `if (img[x,y] == 0):` -- the second image is almost all black, so I'd expect the centroid of all the black piexels to be roughly in the middle of the image (which it is). Maybe you ought to invert that second image before you process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is quite simple. Your algorithm processes only black pixels, due to this condition: `if (img[x,y] == 0):`. Your image of the boundary contains a large proportion of black pixels. It is safe to assume that the centroid of all the black pixels in such image would be very close to the center of the image.

The image in question is 402 pixels wide, and 302 pixels high. Your algorithm gives us `(x=201, y=151)` as the centroid -- this matches the expectation.

To correctly process the object boundary, we need to make the boundary black, and everything else white. This is simple, just invert the image (e.g. `255 - img`). Then your algorithm returns `(x=165, y=123)`, which makes a lot more sense.

### Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def getCentroid(img):
   row, col = img.shape

   xVal = 0
   yVal = 0
   n = 0.0

   for x in range(0,row):
      for y in range(0,col):
         if (img[x,y] == 0):
            xVal += x
            yVal += y
            n += 1.0

   xVal /= n
   yVal /= n

   return [np.int64(np.round(xVal)),np.int64(np.round(yVal))]

a = cv2.imread('cnt.png', 0)

c1 = getCentroid(a) # Original
c2 = getCentroid(255 - a) # Inverse

b = cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.circle(b, (c1[1], c1[0]), 3, (0,0,255))
cv2.circle(b, (c2[1], c2[0]), 3, (0,255,0))

cv2.imwrite('cnt_out.png', b)
```

### Sample output

Note: Red is the centroid from original image, Green from the inverted image.

[image: Sample output image]

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to replace (img[x,y] == 0) to (img[x,y] == 255) after doing boundary following algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is easy: just average all boundary pixel coordinates. However, this will not be the real centroid. To find the real one, average over all pixels contained in the object (not only the boundary).

Answer (score 0):

Averaging the boundary would work if the object were **convex**.  A convex object is one such that no connection between two internal points would intersect its boundary.  The simplest method to **break an object into such components** is probably to break it up into non-overlapping rectangles while trying to keep the number of rectangles to a minimum.  The average of the centroids of the rectangles (multiplied by the rectangles' area) will be the centroid of the object.